# Is my basic coil gun schematic correctly wired?

Tags: schematics, coil, thyristor

Recently, I came up with the idea of integrating a coil gun into a marble machine to accelerate an iron marble. I've done a fair bit of research into other people's projects, and ended up mixing what I've come across into a basic two-stage schematic.

However, it's my first time working with thyristors and inductors, so just wanted to make sure I haven't made any glaringly obvious mistakes.

[image: 1]

Trigger pulses will be sent from the digital pins of an Arduino Nano, with the timing pre-set through software.
If it helps, my capacitors are both rated to 450V (1000uF in first stage and 680uF in second stage), and I think I'll use [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005759855607.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.31595376ivkTys&mp=1#nav-specification) voltmeter and [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003358487848.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.31595376ivkTys&mp=1) boost module.

Also, I've been a bit concerned about the lack of current, given that 12V 5A will be boosted all the way to 390V. This leaves only 123.1mA assuming 80% efficiency…
If anyone can relieve (or confirm) my anxiety, It would be greatly appreciated.

**PS** - If anyone else is in a similar situation to me, below are some helpful links for coil gun basics:

- [An Optimal Design of Capacitor-Driven Coilgun](https://coilgun.info/theorymath/ieee/optimal.pdf)
- [power-labs.com](https://power-labs.com/coilguns/#Gauss%20Gun%20Theory:)
- [Benjamin Marshall's 'Coil Gun Design Guide'](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QH2dbDUKwIGOhsAcvSpi7IVG3i0CstFYAVaMQ2GnlEg/edit?usp=sharing)
- [LetsBuildOne's '.50 Cal Coil Gun'](https://www.instructables.com/50-cal-Coil-Gun/)
- [LetsBuildOne's 'Coil Gun Projectiles'](https://www.instructables.com/Coil-Gun-Projectiles/)
- [coilgun.info](https://coilgun.info/mark2/home.htm)

Comment: Why don't you use a simulation tool to check your circuit operation? That's what all the pros do and, so do a lot of the hobbyists. There are free tools available that can do this.